# perl reference and dereference on return statement

Tags: perl, reference

I am learning perl, and have a problem related to references.
I am working on the function get_id.

If i return `$self->{_id}`, I will get two array address which cannot run (c).

In my understanding, `$a` is the reference and `@{$a}` is array and `@{$a}[0]` would return the value 0?

This is my first time post question on stackoverflow, therefore the explaination may not clear enough, sorry about that.

```
@a1 = [0]  
@a2 = [1]

my self{   
  _id = [\@a1,\@a2]; }   //given
  
sub get_id(){
   my $self      = shift;
   return  $self->{_id};
}

sub print{
    
...

   my $a = $obj -> get_id();

   my $b = @{$a}[0] * 100;    // c  (given)

..
}
```

Comment: The first statement of your code is actually `@a1 = [0] @a2 = [1] my self { ... }`. Which will give a whole bunch of errors if you try and run it, because your lines do not end in semi-colons. `//` is an operator in Perl, not a comment. `my self { ... }` is not a valid statement. You should never post code that you are not actually running, as it just wastes peoples time. The code you post should be runnable, and it should demonstrate your problem.

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `$arr` is a reference to an array, `@$arr` or `@{ $arr }` is the array it refers to. The first (or zeroth) element of the array is `$arr->[0]` (or `$$arr[0]`, but the arrow notation is more common).

The following

```
my @arr = [0];
```

creates an array with a single element, and that element is an array reference. To get the 0, you need to do

```
$arr[0]->[0]
```

which can be shortened to

```
$arr[0][0]
```

To create an array with 0 as the single element, use

```
my @arr = (0);
```

BTW, don't use `$a` and `$b`, they are special variables used in [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort). Lexicalising them with [my](http://p3rl.org/my) can lead to bugs that are hard to debug.